# How can I re-partition my Samsung NP530?

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, ssd

I've recently bought a Samsung NP530 which has 16GB SSD and 1TG. the problem is, I need to install Windows 7 Ultimate on the SSD but it won't fit on the 16GB SSD alone. What's the best partitions plan can I use in my case? How to make the best of those two drives together?

Answer (score 1):

[If it is a Seagate hybrid drive](http://forums.seagate.com/t5/Momentus-XT-Momentus-Momentus/Momentus-XT-Frequently-Asked-Questions/td-p/52701), you cannot manage or even access the SSD portion of it, its done by the hard drive firmware. Nothing you can do.

If it is indeed 2 separate drives, one SSD and one regular platter hard drive, then I don't see why you cannot install W7 on the SSD, but you will run out of room fast if you install many programs or updates, there is a trick of sorts to [move the user account to a separate drive](http://www.starkeith.net/coredump/2009/05/18/how-to-move-your-windows-user-profile-to-another-drive/), which will help cut down on using up your 16gb so fast.

Before I did anything I would be sure I could recover the laptop to factory layout, in case something does not work out. I would assume Samsung has it done correctly and optimized, I would be hesitant to change anything until I knew exactly what Samsung has done using the current configuration.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. When I check it in the device manager, it says SanDisk iSSD 16G and there is another normal hard drive which is Samsung 1T. When I go to computer management-disk management, I see 2 disks. The first one is 1 T and the second one is the SSD which has 2 partitions. So I can't select what disk to install Window? and if not, will I be able to install the OS normally like I have only one disk?

Comment: I guess I am wrong, the specs said hybrid, but your appears to be 2 separate drives, one SSD and one normal platter spinning drive.

Comment: @FanarALHAYALI check my edit to my answer

Comment: I agree it's most likely Samsung has done special configurations to those disks because the Windows folder is on the normal spinning drive and like I mentioned before the SSD disk can't be accessed. I don't know if this is will help you a little bit, when I check the SSD in the disk management a 8.6GB labeled as primary partition and the other partition is labeled as hibernation. Does that make sense to you?

Comment: I would look for documentation in the manual for that laptop. That info should be in there somewhere. I would only be guessing what Samsung did.

Answer (score 0):

If I see this right, this is a pretty current machine. Maybe you need to install the Intel RAID driver during windows setup to have the ssd used as a cache. Otherwise the SSD seems to be to small for anything.

Comment: okay, the spec says Hardisk: 500GB/16GB HDD/SSD hybrid drive so you need to have this special driver. you should be able to get it from the samsung website then

Comment: Thanks for the reply Alexander! I didn't know I have a hybrid disk :). It's 1000GB/16GB. OK now, how can I deal with this hybrid? When I format the PC and go for a fresh Windows 7 installation, how should I partition the 2 disks?

Answer (score -1):

You should not install Windows on the SSD, as the SSD on this machine is not intended to hold the operating system. As you've noticed, 10GB of the SSD is used for ExpressCache and 4GB is used for hibernation.  I'm also concerned about the reliability of the SSD if you use it to install the operating system.

You'll make the most of your experience if you upgrade the pre-installed Windows 7 Home Premium to Ultimate, rather than trying to replace it with a Windows installation on the SSD.